# enhanced FCM clustering in python-opencv

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

are there any functions in opencv, python that I can do enhanced FCM clustering on images?

**EnFCM:** by Szilagyi, L., et al., "MR brain image segmentation using an enhanced fuzzy C-means algorithm ", 2003

Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 1):

I've checked documentations of both [OpenCV 2.4.12](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/clustering.html) and [OpenCV 3.1.0](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d5/d38/group__core__cluster.html#gsc.tab=0) about clustering and none of them has Enchaced FCM Clustering implemented.

OpenCV has a powerful documentation about its functionality, you can directly search it for any function.